# VBA. Export only visible sheet to individual workbook

Tags: excel, vba, show-hide, visible

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook() 
    ‘Select all visible and hide sheet’
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N& 
    MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & _ 
    Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4) 
    With Application 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 
        .DisplayAlerts = False 
         '      End With
        On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
        MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
        For N = 1 To Sheets.Count 
            Sheets(N).Activate 
            SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 
            Cells.Copy 
            Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet) 
            With ActiveWorkbook 
                With .ActiveSheet 
                    .Paste 
                    .Name = SheetName 
                    [A1].Select 
                End With 
                 'save book in this folder
                .SaveAs Filename:=MyFilePath _ 
                & "\" & SheetName & ".xlsx" 
                .Close SaveChanges:=True 
            End With 
            .CutCopyMode = False 
        Next 
    End With 
    Sheet1.Activate 
End Sub
```

I have a workbook, that contains many sheets which have visible and hide ones. I only want to export each visible sheet to individual workbook. this current code above can do the export for all the sheet in the workbook but I have to delete them 1 by 1 after that. Hope that explains my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to add to your code to exclude hidden sheets is a simple [`If..Then` statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php) to check whether the [`Worksheet.Visible` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible) is `True` or `False`.

`If Not yourWorsheet.Visible Then...` ... then you skip that worksheet.

---

The following procedure is a **simpler overall approach** to what you're trying to accomplish...

## Export Visible worksheets to their own workbooks:

The [`worksheet.Copy` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) will create a new workbook if neither *`Before`* nor *`After`* are specified.

```
Sub saveVisibleSheetsAsXLSM()       'saves all visible sheets as new xlsx files
    Const exportPath = "x:\yourDestinationPath\"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wbNew As Workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets                      'for each worksheet
        If ws.Visible Then                                  'if it's visible:
            Debug.Print "Exporting: " & ws.Name
            ws.Copy '(if no params specified, COPY creates + activates a new wb)
            Set wbNew = Application.ActiveWorkbook          'get new wb object
            wbNew.SaveAs exportPath & ws.Name & ".xlsm", 52 'save new wb
            wbNew.Close                                     'close new wb
            Set wbNew = Nothing                             'cleanup 
        End If
    Next ws
    Set ws = Nothing                                        'clean up 
End Sub
```

> ### `Worksheet.Copy` Remarks:
>
> If you don't specify either `Before` or `After`, Microsoft Excel creates a new [workbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook) that contains the copied sheet object that contains the copied [`Worksheet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet) object. The newly created workbook holds the [`Application.ActiveWorkbook` Property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.activeworkbook) property and contains a single worksheet. The single worksheet retains the [`Worksheet.Name` Property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name) and [`Worksheet.CodeName` Property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) properties of the source worksheet. If the copied worksheet held a worksheet code sheet in a VBA project, that is also carried into the new workbook.
>
> An array selection of multiple worksheets can be copied to a new blank [Workbook Object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook) object in a similar manner.
>
> <sub>(Source: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy#remarks))</sub>

Comment: Can I check if I want to infuse the If then statement to my existing code. How should I go about doing it?